# Sending MailEnvelope with multiple email accounts

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sending a `MailEnvelope` through macro in Excel. I have only one email account added to Outlook, but this will have to work with multiple accounts. Unfortunately I can't access the `From` property. Does excel ask you to chose an account when you have more than one? How can I solve this?

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I want to use `MailEnvelope`, not the Microsoft Outlook Object Library.

Comment: My apologies, I have not used the `MailEnvelope` class before